# Seed file isn't populating data in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So when I run this command to reset my db

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
```

In my console I can see all tables are created but my Videos table is the only table that isn't populated. My Videos.rb file depends on tables that are already created

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :product
 belongs_to :user
 validates :product, :source, :description, presence: true
end
```

The Video table is created

```
create_table "videos", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "product_id"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.string   "source"
 t.text     "description"
 t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

And my seed file doesn't have any syntax errors

```
videos = Video.create(
  [
     { product_id: products[0].id, user_id: users[0].id, source: '0mB7cgAKbEY', description: '' },
    { product_id: products[0].id, user_id: users[0].id, source: 'T7ZqdzO4cm4', description: '' },
    { product_id: products[0].id, user_id: users[0].id, source: 'MA3dJQU4J2M', description: '' }
])
```

But for some reason there's no data in my video table

Comment: Try using `create!`, that way you'll see the errors if there are any.

Comment: Use `create!` to see if there's a validation error.

Comment: k yep ;( I guess my description as '' counts as being blank, thanks guys